# Whats wrong with my minimap implementation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I need to create a minimap for my web-app, which shows where on the page you are now. To work with the canvas I'm using RaphaelJS library. So here my code.

**Creating Raphael instance and setup two canvas - main one (5000x5000) and for the minimap (280x180):**

```
var paper = Raphael('minimap', 280, 180),
paperC = Raphael('container', 5000, 5000);
```

Then create a "viewport" on minimap, thats shows your position on page:

```
viewport = paper.rect(document.documentElement.scrollLeft * scaleX, 
document.documentElement.scrollTop * scaleY, window.innerWidth * scaleX, 
window.innerHeight * scaleY).attr({'stroke' : '#000000', 'fill' : 
'#F0F0F0'})
```

`scaleX = 280 / 5000` and `scaleY = 180 / 5000` - they are needed for scaling values when moving across canvases.

Function for drag'n'drop scroll type on the main canvas:

```
function dragWindow() {
var clicked = false,
startX, startY,
$d = $(document);
function updatePosition(e) {
    viewport.attr({'x' : $d.scrollLeft() * scaleX, 'y' : $d.scrollTop() * scaleY});
  $d.scrollLeft($d.scrollLeft() + (startX - e.pageX));
  $d.scrollTop($d.scrollTop() + (startY - e.pageY));
}
function startDragScroll(e){
  clicked = true;
  startX = e.pageX;
  startY = e.pageY;
}
function moveDragScroll(e){
  clicked && updatePosition(e);
}
function endDragScroll(){
  clicked = false;
}
document.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragScroll);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveDragScroll);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', endDragScroll);
}
```

In this row `viewport.attr({'x' : $d.scrollLeft() * scaleX, 'y' : $d.scrollTop() * scaleY});` i'm assign x and y values to "viewport" on minimap;
Thats all work fine. I'm draggin on main big cnavas and "viewport" on minimap moves correctly as the scroll through document.

Function for drag "viewport" on minimap:

```
drag = function(){
    this.ox = this.attr('x');
    this.oy = this.attr('y');
};
move = function(dx, dy){
this.attr({'x' : Math.min(Math.max(this.ox + dx, 0), 280 - this.attr('width')), 'y' : Math.min(Math.max(this.oy + dy, 0), 180 - this.attr('height'))});
};
up = function(){

};
```

This also work correctly. "Viewport" moves on minimap and does not go beyond.

But strange things coming when i try to change document scroll while dragging "viewport" on minimap. Here's code, just adding two rows in `move` function:

```
$d.scrollLeft(this.attr('x') / scaleX);
$d.scrollTop(this.attr('y') / scaleY);
```

And now, when I try to move the "viewport" on the minimap, it quickly jumps to one of the corners of the minimap and that's it. The document also scrolls to the end in the same direction.

So, guys, what's may go wrong in this simple code?

Comment: Oh, i think it happens because `dx` and `dy` values in Raphael `move` function change dramatically when i try to scroll document. Maybe they rely on the current coordinates of the entire document, not the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: problem solved by changing the type of document scrolling. I set the `width` and`height` of the main canvas to `window.innerWidth` and`window.innerHeight` and change these values ​​in the `$(window).resize()` event handler.
So now i have scrollbars on a div, not on body and i'm changing `.scrollLeft()` and `.scrollRight()` values on that div. The values `dx` and`dy` are correct in the Raphael `move` function, because now the document does not scroll.